# tf.keras "history not defined"... but it appears to me to be defined

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tf.keras

I am building a simple model in TensorFlow for an introductory course that I am taking.  I cannot find the reason for the error "history not defined." I would be extremely grateful for any assistance in identifying the source of this error and fixing it.

Here is the code:

```
def train_model(model, scaled_train_images, train_labels):
    history = model.fit(scaled_train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=256)

# Run function to train the model
train_model(model, scaled_train_images, train_labels)
```

Output:

```
Train on 60000 samples

Epoch 1/5
60000/60000 [===] - 56s 936us/sample - loss: 0.0623 - accuracy: 0.9809

Epoch 2/5
60000/60000 [===] - 56s 932us/sample - loss: 0.0538 - accuracy: 0.9838

Epoch 3/5
60000/60000 [===] - 56s 925us/sample - loss: 0.0475 - accuracy: 0.9858

Epoch 4/5
60000/60000 [===] - 55s 923us/sample - loss: 0.0422 - accuracy: 0.9869- los

Epoch 5/5
60000/60000 [===] - 55s 917us/sample - loss: 0.0380 - accuracy: 0.9883

#Load the model history into a pandas DataFrame

frame = pd.DataFrame(history.history)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-895ca3f31ddf> in <module>
    1 # Run this cell to load the model history into a pandas DataFrame
    2 
----> 3 frame = pd.DataFrame(history.history)

NameError: name 'history' is not defined
```

Comment: You probably need to run all of the cells first, starting with the first one.  Each one builds of the other.

Comment: Very good advice.  I have done that repeatedly.  Each time the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

The history variable is only defined inside the train_model function and therefore is not accessible outside.

To fix this return it:

```py
def train_model(model, scaled_train_images, train_labels):
    return model.fit(scaled_train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=256)

history = train_model(model, scaled_train_images, train_labels)

frame = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
```

Comment: Your solution makes clear intuitive sense.  I applied it precisely as you wrote above and got an "unexpected indent" error message.

Comment: Got it!  history = train_model(... ) both calls the defined function and makes it available as history.  @Matteo, I would not have figured this out without your help.  Thank you!

Comment: @mco remember to accept the answer if it resolved your problem :)